# How to remove google logo in the google map using javascrip

Tags: javascript, google-maps

How guys, I using google map in my project, and I want to delete the google logo and and condition terms in th bottom the picture below:
[image]

I used this code but it doesnt work :

```
this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapNativeElement.nativeElement, {

  zoom: 4,
  center: { lat: 53.0000, lng: 9.0000 },
  mapTypeControl: false,
  disableDefaultUI: true,

  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
```

Comment: Probably you can do it, but Google can ban you - it is not allowed according to its terms and conditions.

Comment: aah Ok , thnaks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Try to respect the [Google Maps Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms?csw=1#9-license-requirements)

**9.4 Attribution.**

- *Content provided to you through the Service may contain the Brand Features of Google, its strategic partners, or other third-party rights holders of content that Google indexes. When Google provides those Brand Features or other attribution through the Service, you must display such attribution as provided (or as described in the Maps APIs Documentation) and must not delete or alter the attribution.*
- *You must conspicuously display the "powered by Google" attribution (and any other attribution(s) required by Google in the Maps APIs Documentation) on or adjacent to the relevant Service search box and Google search results. If you use the standard Google search control, or the standard Google search control form, this attribution will be included automatically, and you must not modify or obscure this automatically-generated attribution.*

Developers don't have the authority to replace the logo even though it's possible.

**[UPDATE]**

*3.2.3 Requirements for Using the Services.*

*(b) Attribution.  Customer will display all attribution that (i) Google provides through the Services (including branding, logos, and copyright and trademark notices); or (ii) is specified in the Maps Service Specific Terms. Customer will **not modify, obscure, or delete** such attribution.*